# I can't get the information outside of subscribe section with Observable and HttpClient in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-httpclient, angular2-observables, rxjs-observables

My backend is working, but in the frontend I have the service:

`getDoctorById(sId : number): Observable<Doctor>{ let url = this.baseURL+"/id/"+sId return this.httpClient.get<Doctor>(`${url}`); }`

In my component:

`let serverGetDoctor =  this.doctorService.getDoctorById(this.selectedD); serverGetDoctor.subscribe(data=>{ this.sch.idDoctor = data;  // here I get the correct information });`

but here "outside" I can't get it

`console.log("doctor schedule: "+ this.sch.idDoctor.name);`  // this line generates error:  ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

I tried changing the code, but any works:

opt 1: In the service put the .pipe and tap:

`getDoctorById(sId : number): Observable<Doctor>{ let url = this.baseURL+"/id/"+sId return this.httpClient.get<Doctor>(`${url}`).pipe( tap( _ => console.log("obtuvo el doctor en service")) ); }`

opt 2: In the component :

I tried to do it in other method, but out of method doesn't work
`serverGetDoctor.subscribe((data: Doctor) =>  this.asignarDoctor(data))`

opt 3:

`serverGetDoctor.pipe(map(data=>this.sch.idDoctor = data));`

opt 4:

`serverGetDoctor.pipe(tap(data=>{this.sch.idDoctor = data})).subscribe();`

Comment: Please post complete code examples and not just fragments. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Observables are *asynchronous*. It's not possible to tell this from the given code fragments, but your code is probably written like Observables were *synchronous*.

Comment: I think what @JSONDerulo is trying to say is that at the time where you try to write the value to the console it hasn't yet arrived on the observable.

Comment: Post your whole code. I have to check which function you are calling the variable to log.